# Passing in context variables to form

Tags: python, django, forms, view, django-forms

I want to pass in the `parent_username` variable in the below view function to the `LevelTestModelForm`, so that I could fill in one of the form inputs as that variable automatically.
Here is the view:

```
def LevelTestView(request, pk):
    parent_username = User.objects.get(pk=pk).username
    form = LevelTestModelForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LevelTestModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return reverse("profile-page")
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "leads/leveltest.html", context)
```

All I want is that the user can submit this form without having to input the parent_username. I honestly don't want the field to even show up on the form, but just add it automatically when the user submits the form.
I hope you guys could help. Thanks a lot.

LevelTestModelForm for additional information:

```
class LevelTestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = parent
    class Meta:
        model = LevelTest
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'age',
            'username',
        )
```

Comment: Why do you want to fill in an input element, and not just add this to the instance wrapped in the form?

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Can you please clarify? All I want is that the user can submit this form without having to input the parent_username. I honestly don't want the field to even show up on the form, but just add it automatically when the user submits the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest passing it as an `initial` argument to the form like so:
(supposing there is a `parent` field in your form)

```
form = LevelTestModelForm(initial={'parent': parent_username })
```

Comment: It says that 'parent' is not defined when I add it like above(I edited in the  form to my question)

Comment: I suppose that `username` in your form corresponds to `parent` in mine and then in should be `form = LevelTestModelForm(initial={'username': parent_username })`

Comment: Thanks so much! It's working now. Man, I've been struggling with this for hours. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, do you happen to know how I can make the username field uneditable by the user? So, basically it is a read-only.

Comment: from the top of my head I would add something like 
`form.fields['yourfieldname'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True` under
`form = LevelTestModelForm()` but dont quote me on that

Comment: Yeah... it didn't work. I get the error message: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Add this to your form then 

`from django.forms import Textarea`
and under Meta
`widgets = {
            'yourfield': Textarea(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
        }`

Comment: Yes delete the `form.fields['yourfieldname'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True under form = LevelTestModelForm()` and in your form 
`class Meta:
        model = LevelTest
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'age',
            'username',
        )
widgets = {'username': Textarea(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230651/discussion-between-david-louda-and-john-song).